# Error: CHKJ2800E: <local> interface com.ibm.wsspi.sca.ejb.module.ServiceLocal,

Tags: interface, local

I was working fine with my EJB until this afternoon, suddenly I am getting this error in every ejb.

```
CHKJ2800E: <local> interface com.ibm.wsspi.sca.ejb.module.ServiceLocal, or one of its supertypes, cannot be reflected. Check the classpath.
```

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: did you change anything prior to this error or is it totally out of the blue?